# detecting any selected dropdown value with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that detects all input value changes with keyup:

Jquery:

```
// detect all inputs

$('.inputChange').each(function() {
   // Save current value of element
   $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val())

   // Look for changes in the value
   $(this).bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
      // If value has changed...
      if ($(this).data('oldVal') != $(this).val()) {
       // Updated stored value
       $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val())
        currentVal = $(this).val()
       // Do action
       inputElement = $(this).attr('data-element')
       inputProperty = $(this).attr('data-property')
       inputUnit = $(this).attr('data-unit')
        updateAllCSS(inputElement, inputProperty, currentVal + inputUnit)
     }
   });
 });
```

HTML:

```
    <input class="inputChange" data-element=".homeTemplate #colaAlpha h1" data-property="font-size" data-unit="px">px
```

I now need to do another that will get the selected dropdown values from this HTML:

```
     <select class="selectChange" data-element=".homeTemplate #colaAlpha" data-property="height" data-unit="px">
         <option value="8">8px</option>
         <option value="12">12px</option>
         <option value="21">21px</option>
     </select>px
```

I was wondering how I should go about doing this? is there perhaps a propertychange event that will work?

Comment: have you tried anything already ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/change/:

```
$(".selectChange").change(function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, can I make this apply across unlimited select options?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the above complex input detection code, here is the select code that will work for any of the selects on my page- it uses the selected value and also the data tags:

```
$('.selectChange').change(function() {
    updateAllCSS($(this).attr('data-element'), $(this).attr('data-property'), $(this).val() + $(this).attr('data-unit'))
});
```